# Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

trying to make a currency wallet in my discord bot made a json file called pointbank.json and I'm trying to get the users that are in it so I don't add the same user multiple times

```
 import os
 import discord
 import json
 os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\bot")

 async def getbankdata():
  with open('pointbank.json', "r") as f:
     users = json.load(f)

  return users
```

error when called:
(balance and open_account functions call getbankdata)

```
File "c:\Users\User\source\repos\bot\gamebot.py", line 44, in balance 
   await open_account(ctx.author)
File "c:\Users\User\source\repos\bot\gamebot.py", line 56, in open_account
    users = await getbankdata()
File "c:\Users\User\source\repos\bot\gamebot.py", line 70, in getbankdata
      users = json.load(f)
(more lines)
Command raised an exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: is `pointbank.json` empty? Maybe add `{}` when you first make the file

Comment: I do have them.

Comment: Moved it to after the on_ready event and it worked